# how do i use provider in this situation

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-theme

I want to create a change app theme mode and I saw a way of creating it with Provider but I'm new to Provider. For Example, I want to add some codes like this

[image: highlight code] (the highlighted code)

in my main which consists of many routes

[image: my main]

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the theme of the app, then you need to move provider up so it can cover the widget (App in this case) state,
You could do something like this in your main method :

```
runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(

    create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
    child:MyApp()

);
```

now in the case of children you could simply call provider in the build method like this

```
Widget build(){
   var themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
}
```

or you could use the consumer widget

```
Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
builder: (context, provider, child) {
//return something
}

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to move your `ChangeNotifierProvider` to your `runApp()` method

```
runApp(
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(
          create: (_) => ThemeProvider(),
          child: MyApp(),
        ),
      ),
```

Where your `MyApp()` is just all of your app extracted to its own widget.

Then you can actually easily access it as you wish with a `Consumer` widget on your `build` method.

```
return Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
    builder: (BuildContext context, ThemeProvider provider, _) {
    return MaterialApp(
     theme: provider.myTheme,
     ... 
   );
  }
)
```